# How to create a one-hot-encoded dataframe of all possible combinations of X columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations, one-hot-encoding

I have a pandas dataframe with 0 rows and 58 columns, but for the sake of illustration let's assume I have a dataframe with 0 rows and 3 columns that looks like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |

I need to expand this table to represent all possible combinations of one-hot-encoded vectors like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

pd.DataFrame(list(product(*([[0,1]]*len(df.columns))) ), columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     0     0     0
1     0     0     1
2     0     1     0
3     0     1     1
4     1     0     0
5     1     0     1
6     1     1     0
7     1     1     1
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(list(product([0,1],repeat=len(df.columns))), columns=df.columns)` ?

Comment: @Chris yes, that too indeed. I always forgot about the `repeat` option.

Comment: Thanks Quang! Would you happen to know how to calculate the number of rows that this will generate without running the code?

Comment: @NegativeCorrelation `2**(len(df.columns))`, so you might not want to do so with all 58 columns here.

Comment: Indeed, but thank you :)